# Creating pdf from membership results in blank page

Tags: civimember, pdf

After identifying contacts for a letter from Find Member and picking the template, and clicking on Create pdf or the other formats (same with Preview too). I get a blank page and the following error: "Failed to open http://www.site.org/administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/member/search" with an HTML error: "HTML1527: DOCTYPE expected. Consider adding a valid HTML5 doctype: "".

I am using tokens from both contacts and membership.  I can create a pdf from Contacts but all the membership tokens are blank.  This worked last month when I created the pdfs from membership.  Did something change in .8 .9 or .10?

Aaron
Joomla 3.6.2, CiviCRM 4.7.10, PHP 5.6.24,

Comment: This is happening with contributions as well. We are on Wordpress 4.5.3, Civi 4.7.10, and PHP 5.5.38

Comment: This is still a problem for me. I cannot assemble any merged documents that have custom tokens.  Did something changed betwee Civi 4.7.8 and Civi 4.7.10 dealing with custom tokens?